# sum of files' contents matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows

I want to sum files which I created with `fprintf`. I have 5 text files that contain something like this  (1 column 8 rows):

```
0.1811  
0.0889  
-0.1073  
-0.0777  
-0.0596  
0.0971  
0.1021  
0.3730
```

I'm trying to load those files into workspace and sum those columns. I could sum columns of two files, but with the last 3 files sums works only for last rows (row number 8). I understand it has something to do with loading and opening files. The last two files were loaded with:

```
SumFid=fopen(MyFile,'a');   %this is how my 2 files work opened
FID=fopen(FirstFile);  
MatrixSub = load(FirstFile);  
m = textscan(FID,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f');  
horzcat(m{:})
```

While for the other 3 files I'm using:

```
Wfid=fopen(VFile,'a');  
Mat = load(VFile);  
VData = fscanf(Wfid,'%f',[8,1]);
```

When I try to use same `texscan` and `horzcat` as with the previous two it gives *error out of memory*, but with the latter code it only sums last rows of those file contents when I try:

```
for i = i:8  
  Sum = A+B % this from first 2 files works  
  Sum3Files = file1+file2+files3;        
end
```

I know it looks probably pretty trivial but I'm new in MATLAB and would appreciate your help much.

Comment: I don't have Matlab at hand right now, but the line `Wfid=fopen(VFile,'a');`  will open a file for append, try 'r' for read.  The loop at the last block code has no dependance on i (you might also want to use another letter because i is sqrt(-1))

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tried 'r' instead of 'a' but still same. I also undertsand that things in loop do not relate to i but i dont know how to write it so it sums all files row by row..it worked for previous bit of code where i used 'horzcat' so i tried same here to.i dont know how to relate i to file contents - i guess it doesnt work because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this is what you're after:

```
total = 0;
files = {'data.txt' 'data2.txt'};  % add more files here

for ii = 1:numel(files)

    fid = fopen(files{ii});
        C = textscan(fid, '');        
    fclose(fid);

    total = total + [C{:}];

end
```

Comment: Hi, thank for your help. I tried this tip. i probably was not clear sorry. I need sum of elements row by row. here 'total' gives me one number in the end,sum of all elements. while i want to get a matrix with 1 column and 8 rows..in other words if you look at first bit of my question i need similar output.that means sum row by row. so total should be 8 rows 1 column.

Comment: :Thanks a lot for your help!it works well this time. it was very useful to learn how to put files into array so that to read through them after.I will use it again.Many thanks.

Comment: @user1822224: Well, glad to help! If you think my answer was useful, you can upvote and/or accept it by clicking the up/down/tickmark sy,bols at the top-left of this question.